# paper-ripple mouseDown event handler downAction Override

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Polymer 1.1

In [paper ripple source code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-ripple/blob/master/paper-ripple.html) they have the `mouseDown` event handler:

```
  /** @param {Event=} event */
  downAction: function(event) {
    var xCenter = this.containerMetrics.width / 2;
    var yCenter = this.containerMetrics.height / 2;
```

In documentation it states:

> paper-ripple listens to "mousedown" and "mouseup" events so it would display ripple effect when touches on it. You can also defeat the default behavior and manually route the down and up actions to the ripple element

However, in my custom element I am not able to override this handler:

```
        <paper-ripple
          fit
          id="ripple"
          initial-opacity="0.95"
          opacity-decay-velocity="0.98">
        </paper-ripple>
      </section>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "portfolio-page",
     ...
      downAction: function(e) {
        console.log('sssssssssssssssssssssssss');
      },
      upAction: function(e) {
        this.$.ripple.upAction();
      }
```

When I induce the action of paper ripple by clicking on my element, I do not get any console output.

How do I override the default `downAction` handler for `mouseDown` that `paper-ripple` listens for as documented in [paper-ripple doc](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-ripple)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely documentation assumes that one should add a listener, like

```
listeners: {
    'up' : 'upAction',
    'down' : 'downAction',
}
```

you still can override the methods, but that's probably not how ripple element was supposed to be used:

```
ready: function(){
   this.ripplesDownAction = this.$.ripple.downAction.bind(this.$.ripple);
   this.$.ripple.downAction = this.downAction.bind(this);
},

downAction: function(e) {
    console.log('sssssssssssssssssssssssss');
    this.ripplesDownAction();
}
```

Comment: The issue I have with add a listener is that there is already one listening...and for efficiency wanted to not add a additional one. I will most likely query the shady element and just modifiy the existing `downAction` method. I don't think documentation intended this though since they stated to `override` `downAction`.